# Is it possible to have multiple RouteCollections and switch depending on language at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

We have a fairly large RouteCollection setup in RegisterRoutes() and we need to support Russian urls. This means that most of our MapRoute() urls need to be Russian.

Rather than duplicate the affected MapRoute() calls and translate the url to Russian, I'm wondering if it's possible to have multiple route collections and select which one MVC will use at runtime based on the subdomain eg; "ru."?

Without multiple RouteCollections as we add more and more languages we'll be duplicating more and more routes which will cause maintenance problems and inefficient routing.

By the way, all subdomains leads to the same asp.net mvc application and we use the subdomain element to globalize the resources.

Here is an example route and its Russian translation :

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Content", // Route name
   "Page/{id}", // URL with parameters
   new
   {
      controller = "Content",
      action = "Show",
      id = String.Empty
   } // Parameter defaults
);
```

And in Russian :

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Content", // Route name
   "страница/{id}", // URL with parameters
   new
   {
      controller = "Content",
      action = "Show",
      id = String.Empty
   } // Parameter defaults
);
```

There are dozens of affected routes and each supported language would duplicate them all. At the moment I think a route constraint on the subdomain would be the best method, but it would be good to have separate route collections for each language, and a shared route for unaffected routes.

Comment: this sounds do-able. add your routes to your post and examples of the *russian* routes you

Answer (score 1):

We use something similar:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Language_InfoRoute",
  "{language_code}/{company}/{topic}", 
  "~/content.aspx", true, null, 
  new RouteValueDictionary { { "language_code", "de|fr|en" }, 
  {"company",   "unternehmung|company|entreprise|azienda" } });
```

Instead of having Page or страница as an individual route, you could also have it as a placeholder (company in my example). You can add the language code or just use the different versions for page to detect the language.

Comment: Thanks, we're either going with this or another approach where we translate the url back to english before routing happens, and also wrap Url.Action() to translate outbound urls from English to the target language. There is no perfect solution without the ability to activate specific route collections per request, or a convention based route collection selector (but this requires multiple route collections and asp.net mvc only allows for one which is very limiting when it comes to large multi-lingual sites).